# Help with integrals and Riemann sums.

Tags: integration, riemann-sum

Find $f$, such that

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n(2+\frac{i}{n})\ln(2+\frac{i}{n})}$$

is a Riemann sum of $f$ on the interval $[0,1]$.

Also, how is this connected to the integral of $f$?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If $f$ is a Riemann-integrable function over the interval $[0,1]$, $$ \int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx = \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right).$$ Now read it in the opposite direction, with $f(x)=\frac{1}{(2+x)\log(2+x)}$ (that is for sure Riemann-integrable over $[0,1]$, since it is a continuous function over there)

Comment: The only non-trivial part is to prove that the limit of your sum as $n\to +\infty$ equals $\color{red}{\log\log 3-\log\log 2}$.

Comment: Smebbs-- Just deleted my comment, -- as Jack's comment spells out, it really doesn't make a difference in the limit.

Comment: Thanks @JackD'Aurizio, one question though. Is 

$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n(2+\frac{i}{n})ln(2+\frac{i}{n})} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{(2+\frac{i}{n})ln(2+\frac{i}{n})}$

Comment: Well, $n$ does not depend on $i$, so you are allowed to "factor that term out".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a "Riemann sum" approximating the integral $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ by dividing the distance from a to b into n intervals (so each interval has length $\Delta x= (b- a)/n$ and evaluating $f(x_i)$ where $x_i$ is some value of x inside the $i^{th}$ interval.  If we take it at the left end of the interval, it is $a+ \Delta x$.  Multiply each $f(x_i)$ by $\Delta x$ and sum: $\sum_{i= 0}^n f(x_i)\Delta x$.

Seeing that "n" in the **denominator** I would take $\Delta x= \frac{1}{n}$ and $x_i= 2+ \frac{i}{n}$.  As i goes from 0 to n, $x_i$ goes from $2+ \frac{0}{n}= 2$ to $2+ \frac{n}{n}= 3$ so the integral corresponding to this Riemann sum is $\int_2^3 \frac{1}{xln(x)}dx$.

That can easily be integrated using the substitution u= ln(x).

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: The last interval would be $[x_{n-1},x_n]$ so if using left endpoints as evaluation points one would be evaluating $f(x_{n-1}).$ So that way the sum bounds would be for $i$ from $0$ to $n-1.$ (A sum from $0$ to $n$ has $n+1$ terms so doesn't technically qualify as a Riemann sum. Of course it has no effect on the limit value if this last $x_n$ term is included...)